# How I do wrong with dispatcher configuration, maybe something is missing?

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I don't know what the problem is, not created the beans.
Suppose it's AppInitializer or AppConfig, pics and code below.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/133XHg9460qLGxqvaSBmkdrUt4img68DA?usp=sharing

**Sorry** that I didn't disclose the problem enough, I searched for a long time. **Thanks!**

Comment: Please add the relevant information to your question instead of letting people willing to help click links to get a full picture. Include stacktraces, configes etc.

Answer (score 0):

The error says missing sessionfactory bean,

> 'customerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:

You need to create Sessionfactory bean like below,

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.brest.code.entity" });

    return sessionFactory;
 }

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
}
```

Refer [Spring MVC Hibernate](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring%20mvc%20hibernate%20sessionfactory%20example&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN883IN883&oq=spring%20mvc%20sessionfactory%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.9512j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)